# Mapping Lookup fields in Reporting Snapshots

Tags: snapshot

[image]

I can't map lookup fields for my reporting snapshot. It's not showing me the option to choose a field to map. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

To map a field in the source report to a lookup field on the target object, you must map to the ID of the object associated with the lookup. For example, to map to an opportunity lookup field, you must map to the Opportunity ID. To get the Opportunity ID in the source report, you may need to use a custom report type to include ID and other related fields.

Please refer support article [Link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_mapping_analytic_snap.htm&type=5) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

From the same support article as Ankaiah Bandi is quoting: "A custom summary formula can be mapped only if the grouping level in the reporting snapshot and the grouping level in the custom summary formula match."